# Only execute if Firebase data changed using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing a script in node.js to keep track of firebase data. I want a line to execute but ONLY when there's a change in the database. Meaning that the first time I execute the code, I don't want It to execute because it successfully read from the database. It should only execute If there's change later on.
Here's my code:

```
var forumRef = firebase.database().ref("Forum/ForumIds");
forumRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("new post");       
});
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with firebase you're always going to get the value of whatever node you are reading when you attach a listener. AFAIK there isn't a way to only receive events when your node changes and not upon initial listener attachment. You're best best is probably to just throw away the first invocation of your callback. There isn't even a way to get the previous value from within your callback to see if it's an actual change event or just a result of attaching the listener. Kinda sucks but  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. I guess discarding the frst one is my best bet

Comment: and how would you disregard the first one?